# Merge dataframes based on values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the following datafrmae1

```
column3   column4    ID
car       red        100
car       red        101
car       blue       102
Bike      100cc      200
Bike      150cc      201
Bike      150cc      202
```

And I have dataframe2 as follows

```
column1    value   column2
car         50     xyz
150cc       55     abc
```

Based on column1 values need to merge the two dataframe as and get the Final dataframe as follows

Final dataframe:

```
ID   column1   value   column2
100   car        50     xyz
101   car        50     xyz
102   car        50     xyz
201   150cc      55     abc
202   150cc      55     abc
```

So based on value in the column1 the value need to be merge the dataframes

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot easier to offer a solution if you posted the actual code for your two dataframes. I'm guessing that the final script looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(6),
                    'b':[5,3,6,9,2,4]}, index=list('abcdef'))
df1

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':range(4),
                    'd':[10,20,30, 40]}, index=list('abhi'))
df2

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left').fillna(method='ffill')
df
```

[image]